# OpenCart 2: Multiple Physical Store within same online store

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

How can i sell items from different stores in same Opencart website? 
 I want customize items sold on my online store which is based on OpenCart 2.0 such that customers with different addresses can buy/view different items which is available to shop selected on their neighborhood. This is caused by the reason that I will provide their ordered items from different physical stores with different inventory items.

Comment: you can create multi store, So just track the ip of visitor and redirect to the sub store website nearby.

Comment: number of sub stores are going to be so much so I don't want to install an opencart per each shop.